# R (version 2.15.1) ./configure does not create Makefile in puppet script

Tags: r, makefile, puppet

I am trying to install an old version of R (2.15.1) from source and then automate that installation via puppet. When I run the ./configure from the puppet script, the Makefile is not created. Additionally, the config.status executable is not created. The contents of my source directory after running puppet are the following:

```
ChangeLog    configure     COPYING  etc      m4           Makefile.fw  NEWS      ONEWS   po      share  SVN-REVISION  tools    VERSION-NICK
config.site  configure.ac  doc      INSTALL  Makeconf.in  Makefile.in  NEWS.pdf  OONEWS  README  src    tests         VERSION
```

Here is my puppet script:

```
exec { 'r-base-configure':
    command => '/root/R-2.15.1/configure --enable-R-shlib --with-readline=no',
    require => [File['/root/R-2.15.1.tar.gz'], Exec['r-base-untar'], Package['gfortran']],
    logoutput => true
}
```

Here is the output from puppet (first half omitted thx Stack Overflow):

```
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for complex.h... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for double complex... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether C99 double complex is supported... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether cabs exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether carg exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether cexp exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether clog exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether csqrt exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether cpow exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether ccos exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether csin exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether ctan exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether cacos exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether casin exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether catan exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether ccosh exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether csinh exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether ctanh exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for cblas_cdotu_sub in vecLib framework... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking iconv.h usability... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking iconv.h presence... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for iconv.h... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for iconv... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether iconv accepts "UTF-8", "latin1", "ASCII" and "UCS-*"... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for iconvlist... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for iconv... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for iconv declaration... 
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns:  extern size_t iconv (iconv_t cd, char * *inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft, char * *outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking wchar.h usability... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking wchar.h presence... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for wchar.h... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking wctype.h usability... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking wctype.h presence... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for wctype.h... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether mbrtowc exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether wcrtomb exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether wcscoll exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether wcsftime exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether wcstod exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether mbstowcs exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether wcstombs exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether wctrans exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether iswblank exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether wctype exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether iswctype exists and is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for wctrans_t... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for mbstate_t... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for ICU... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for X... libraries , headers 
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for gethostbyname... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for connect... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for remove... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for shmat... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for IceConnectionNumber in -lICE... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking X11/Intrinsic.h usability... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking X11/Intrinsic.h presence... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for X11/Intrinsic.h... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for XtToolkitInitialize in -lXt... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: using X11 ... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for KeySym... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking X11/Xmu/Atoms.h usability... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking X11/Xmu/Atoms.h presence... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for X11/Xmu/Atoms.h... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: configure: not checking for cairo as pkg-config is not present
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for tclConfig.sh... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for tclConfig.sh in library (sub)directories... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for tkConfig.sh... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for tkConfig.sh in library (sub)directories... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for tcl.h... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for BSD networking... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking if jpeglib version >= 6b... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for main in -lz... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking if libpng version >= 1.2.7... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking tiffio.h usability... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking tiffio.h presence... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for tiffio.h... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for TIFFOpen in -ltiff... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking rpc/types.h usability... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking rpc/types.h presence... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for rpc/types.h... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for rpc/xdr.h... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for XDR support... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether zlib support needs to be compiled... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking mmap support for zlib... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether bzip2 support needs to be compiled... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for lzma_version_number in -llzma... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether PCRE support needs to be compiled... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether leap seconds are treated according to POSIX... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for inline... inline
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for sys/time.h... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for sys/param.h... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for struct stat.st_atim.tv_nsec... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether struct stat.st_atim is of type struct timespec... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for setitimer... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for _LARGEFILE_SOURCE value needed for large files... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether KERN_USRSTACK sysctl is supported... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for visible __lib_stack_end... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for lpr... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for lp... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for paperconf... false
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for java... /usr/bin/java
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for javac... /usr/bin/javac
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for javah... /usr/bin/javah
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for jar... /usr/bin/jar
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether Java compiler works... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether Java compiler works for version 1.4... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether Java interpreter works... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking Java environment... /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for cached Java settings... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for gfortran... gfortran
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran compiler... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether gfortran accepts -g... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran compiler... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether gfortran accepts -g... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether to build static libraries... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for gfortran option to produce PIC... -fPIC
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking if gfortran PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking if gfortran static flag -static works... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking if gfortran supports -c -o file.o... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking if gfortran supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether the gfortran linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for Fortran flag to compile .f90 files... none
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for Fortran flag to compile .f95 files... none
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for gfortran option to support OpenMP... -fopenmp
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for recommended packages... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether NLS is requested... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: 
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: Configuring src/extra/intl directory
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for msgfmt... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for gmsgfmt... :
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for xgettext... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for msgmerge... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether we are using the GNU C Library 2 or newer... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for simple visibility declarations... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for stdint.h... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for getpagesize... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for working mmap... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether integer division by zero raises SIGFPE... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for inttypes.h... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for unsigned long long int... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether the inttypes.h PRIxNN macros are broken... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether imported symbols can be declared weak... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for multithread API to use... none
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking argz.h usability... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking argz.h presence... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for argz.h... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for limits.h... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for sys/param.h... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for getcwd... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for getegid... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for geteuid... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for getgid... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for getuid... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for mempcpy... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for munmap... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for stpcpy... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for strcasecmp... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for strdup... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for strtoul... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for tsearch... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for argz_count... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for argz_stringify... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for argz_next... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for __fsetlocking... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether feof_unlocked is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether fgets_unlocked is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for iconv... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for iconv declaration... (cached) 
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns:  extern size_t iconv (iconv_t cd, char * *inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft, char * *outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for NL_LOCALE_NAME macro... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for bison... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for long long int... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for long double... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for wchar_t... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for wint_t... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for intmax_t... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether printf() supports POSIX/XSI format strings... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether we are using the GNU C Library 2.1 or newer... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for SIZE_MAX... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for CFPreferencesCopyAppValue... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for CFLocaleCopyCurrent... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for ptrdiff_t... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking stddef.h usability... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking stddef.h presence... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for stddef.h... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for string.h... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for asprintf... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for fwprintf... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for putenv... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for setenv... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for setlocale... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for snprintf... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for wcslen... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether _snprintf is declared... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether _snwprintf is declared... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether getc_unlocked is declared... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for nl_langinfo and CODESET... (cached) yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for LC_MESSAGES... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for shared library run path origin... done
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for CFPreferencesCopyAppValue... (cached) no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for CFLocaleCopyCurrent... (cached) no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether included gettext is requested... no
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking for GNU gettext in libc... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking whether to use NLS... yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: checking where the gettext function comes from... libc
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: Finished configuring src/extra/intl directory
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: 
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: using as R_SHELL for scripts ... /bin/bash
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: configure: creating ./config.status
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating Makeconf
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating doc/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating doc/html/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating doc/manual/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating etc/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating etc/Makeconf
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating etc/Renviron
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating etc/ldpaths
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating m4/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating po/Makefile.in
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating share/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/appl/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/extra/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/extra/blas/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/extra/bzip2/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/extra/intl/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/extra/pcre/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/extra/tre/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/extra/xdr/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/extra/xz/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/extra/zlib/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/include/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/include/Rmath.h0
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/include/R_ext/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/Recommended/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/base/DESCRIPTION
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/base/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/compiler/DESCRIPTION
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/compiler/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/datasets/DESCRIPTION
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/datasets/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/graphics/DESCRIPTION
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/graphics/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/grDevices/DESCRIPTION
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/grDevices/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/grDevices/src/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/grDevices/src/cairo/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/grid/DESCRIPTION
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/grid/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/grid/src/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/methods/DESCRIPTION
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/methods/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/methods/src/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/parallel/DESCRIPTION
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/parallel/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/parallel/src/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/profile/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/stats/DESCRIPTION
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/stats/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/stats/src/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/stats4/DESCRIPTION
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/stats4/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/splines/DESCRIPTION
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/splines/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/splines/src/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/tcltk/DESCRIPTION
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/tcltk/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/tcltk/src/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/tools/DESCRIPTION
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/tools/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/tools/src/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/utils/DESCRIPTION
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/library/utils/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/main/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/modules/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/modules/X11/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/modules/internet/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/modules/lapack/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/modules/vfonts/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/nmath/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/nmath/standalone/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/scripts/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/scripts/R.sh
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/scripts/Rcmd
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/scripts/f77_f2c
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/scripts/mkinstalldirs
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/scripts/pager
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/unix/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating tests/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating tests/Embedding/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating tests/Examples/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating tests/Native/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating tools/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating src/include/config.h
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: src/include/config.h is unchanged
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: executing libtool commands
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: executing po-directories commands
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating po/POTFILES
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating po/Makefile
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: executing stamp-h commands
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: 
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: R is now configured for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: 
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns:   Source directory:  /root/R-2.15.1
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns:   Installation directory:/usr/local
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: 
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns:   C compiler:gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns:   Fortran 77 compiler:   gfortran  -g -O2
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: 
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns:   C++ compiler:  g++  -g -O2
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns:   Fortran 90/95 compiler:gfortran -g -O2
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns:   Obj-C compiler:      
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: 
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns:   Interfaces supported:  X11
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns:   External libraries:
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns:   Additional capabilities:   NLS
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns:   Options enabled:   shared R library, shared BLAS, R profiling, Java
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: 
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns:   Recommended packages:  yes
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: 
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: configure: WARNING: you cannot build info or HTML versions of the R manuals
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of the R manuals
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of vignettes and help pages
notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: executed successfully
```

When I run the command ('/root/R-2.14.1/configure --enable-R-shlib --with-readline=no') manually, the Makefile is created successfully.

Comment: Can you run multiple commands via `command`? What do you see in the log if you add `; pwd; ls` to that command? Or alternatively what if you add `cd /root/R-2.15.1` to the beginning of the command?

Comment: Good call - I added a line to ensure the current working directory was /root/R-2.15.1/ and that solved the issue. New command looks like this:

    `exec { 'r-base-configure':
        cwd => '/root/R-2.15.1/',
        command => '/root/R-2.15.1/configure --enable-R-shlib --with-readline=no',
        require => [File['/root/R-2.15.1.tar.gz'], Exec['r-base-untar'], Package['gfortran']],
        logoutput => on_failure
    }`

Comment: from the puppet log, Makefile has been successfully created `notice: / Exec[configure]/returns: config.status: creating Makefile` And in the end of log, it has installed R successfully. What error you think? Are you go to the wrong folder to check the `Makefile`?

Answer (score 1):

The autotools are designed (when used correctly) to support a build directory that differs from the source directory.

You are probably not running that command in the directory you expect are you running it in.

If you can you run multiple commands via command? What do you see in the log if you add `; pwd; ls` to that command?

Alternatively you could try adding `cd /root/R-2.15.1` to the start of the command to ensure you are in the correct directory before you run the configure command.

Alternatively alternatively, you could just use the directory you actually ran configure from as the build directory as that should work just fine.